# Override a function (document.hasFocus) with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need make a script for greasemonkey that override the default document.hasFocus with a method that return true everytime.

Here the code i tried to use:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.innerHTML = 'function document.hasFocus{return true;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

But it doesn't work...

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Check the syntax of the injected script... You should use `document.hasFocus=function(){return true;}`. If you really want short code, its equivalent to `document.hasFocus=function()!0;`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is off, and there might not be a `<head>` tag. Also, avoid use of `innerHTML` when possible. So use:

```
var scriptNode          = document.createElement('script');
scriptNode.type         = "text/javascript";
scriptNode.textContent  = 'document.hasFocus = function () {return true;}';
var targ                = document.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || document.body;
targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
```

---

However, in this case, there is little risk to using `unsafeWindow` (Firefox Greasemonkey).  So the whole script code could be:

```
unsafeWindow.document.hasFocus = function () {return true;};
```

---

If it still "doesn't work", describe ***how*** it doesn't work (expected, versus actual, results; error codes; etc.).  Link to the target page.